# Invalid website id requested

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

Whenever I delete a website, magento returns the error: Invalid website id requested. I've to delete from db tables `core_store` and `core_store_group` the website id and then I can log again in the admin.

Is a Magento bug or I have some problem in my magento instance?

PS: I usually create websites programmatically by the script:

```
$rootCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$rootCategory->setStoreId(0)
    ->setName('Demo')
    ->setPath(1)
    ->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS')
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->save();


$website = Mage::getModel('core/website');
$website->setCode('demo')
    ->setName('demo')
    ->save();

//#addStoreGroup
/** @var $storeGroup Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group */
$storeGroup = Mage::getModel('core/store_group');
$storeGroup->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
    ->setName('demo')
    ->setRootCategoryId($rootCategory->getId())
    ->save();

//#addStore
/** @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store');
$store->setCode('demo_en')
    ->setWebsiteId($storeGroup->getWebsiteId())
    ->setGroupId($storeGroup->getId())
    ->setName('demo_en')
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->save();
```

Comment: How are you deleting the website? Do the `core_store` and `core_store_group` tables have the foreign key set on `website_id`?

Comment: you're right, there aren't foreign keys in the tables!

Answer (score 4):

Your database got somehow corrupted and you are missing the foreign keys on the `core_store` and `core_store_group` tables (and maybe other tables too), so when you deleted the website, the associated store groups and store views weren't also deleted.

You could try running the Magento database repair tool and investigate more from there.

Answer (score 3):

If u got this error after deleting store you can try this solution :

1. Select **core_website** and look for **website_id** attribute.
2. Delete all lines in **core_store** and **core_store_group** tables has **website_id** attribute reference to **core_website.website_id**.

hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the problem @Marina Gociu says. Some of the indexes were not working because of that. Note that after fixing the database you have to flush the caches.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown here: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:950

```
if (empty($this->_websites[$id])) {
    $website = Mage::getModel('core/website');
    if (is_numeric($id)) {
        $website->load($id);
        if (!$website->hasWebsiteId()) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Invalid website id requested.');
```

And the code looks like as you deleted the website and therefore the loading fails. But this is only a guess.

Comment: If i try to import attributes of products i am getting the error like, "Invalid website id requested" how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Magento 1.9 ... I am in a development environment and today, I attempted to test out adding a second store, then delete it as soon as I created it. Seems this caused an issue because now I cannot log into admin without getting an "Invalid Website ID requested" error.

The front end still works great - no problems there. I can place an order, navigate pages, etc., but can't get into admin.

I logged into phpmyadmin and looked at core_stores... see image. Yellow highlight is the one I created, then deleted in admin.

Ideas? Any advice is appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of Magento Site]

Answer (score 0):

If u got this error after deleting store you can try this solution :

Select `core_website` and look for `website_id` attribute.
Delete all lines in `core_store` and `core_store_group` tables has `website_id` attribute reference to `core_website.website_id`.

Very helpful post.